# Problema ao cadastrar objetos aninhados no Mongodb com mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

Possuo a seguinte coleção:

```
    // SUSPEITOS - INICIO //
const suspeitosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nome: { type: String },
  sexo: { type: String },
  corPele: { type: String },
  altura: { type: String },
  peso: { type: String },
  tamanhoCabelo: { type: String },
  corCabelo: { type: String }
})

// ACOES //
const acoesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dataCadastro: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  fonte: { type: String },
  bo: { type: String },
  numeroBo: { type: Number },
  imagem: { type: String },
  relato: { type: String },
  modus: { type: String },
  falhasApuradas: { type: String },
  dataOcorrencia: { type: Date }, 
  latitude: { type: String },
  longitude: { type: String },
  suspeitos: [suspeitosSchema]
})
```

Preciso cadastrar um json que recebo de um formulário via POST, cadastrando está, porém, estou utilizando um multi-select (http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main) e o retorno dele é um outro json, conforme podem perceber abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando envio o formulário através do POST, cadastra, porém os dados que vieram do JSON do Multiselect cadastram da seguinte forma, percebam os itens "**fonte**" e "**suspeitos**":

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a04a17af7a3373fe007cbca"), 
    "fonte" : "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]", 
    "eventosDeRisco" : [

    ], 
    "acoesCriminosas" : [

    ], 
    "alertas" : [

    ], 
    "veiculos" : [

    ], 
    "suspeitos" : [
        {
            "nome" : "[object Object],[object Object]", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a04a17af7a3373fe007cbcb")
        }
    ], 
    "dataCadastro" : ISODate("2017-11-09T18:42:02.842+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Comment: Você vai precisar fazer o mesmo que fez com suspeitos em fonte e notei que o está vindo `name` ao invés de `nome` que foi modelado.

Comment: name é uma propriedade do multiselect, não consigo alterar. 
Não consigo entender a forma certa que deveria passar esse JSON para que cadastrasse corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu modelo, você possui a seguinte especificação:

```
nome: { type: String }
```

Porém você está enviando um array de objetos:

```
nome: [
  {name: "Super Homem", ticked: true},
  {name: "Batmam", ticked: true}
]
```

Ajuste seu *schema* para que `nome` contenha um objeto ao invés de uma *string*, ou modifique o *payload* no lado do cliente antes de enviar para o *backend*.

Comment: Funcionou! Não sabia do SchemaType "array".  
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html   Obrigado!

Comment: @Fred fico feliz em ler isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar. =)